# Accessibility (VoiceOver) on NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, accessibility, nsattributedstring, voiceover

I have a block of text in a `UITextView` built using `NSAttributedString`. I require `VoiceOver` to say something extra when certain portions of the text is touched.

Is it possible to add accessibility attributes to `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: You can set the accessibilityLabel what you want to say, and DO NOT set in AttributedString.

Comment: Definitely Possible ! Refer: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc17/215 You could change the pitch, you could change certain phrases to be read in a different language

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution to this would be a custom subclass of `UITextView`. Then you can return an array of `UIAccessibilityCustomAction` in an override of `accessibilityCustomActions`. These objects not only describe the actions taken by the text view, but they also allow VoiceOver to execute them.